# Masking xml element using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I am new to xslt implementation and would like to do a xml-to-xml transformation using xslt. I have the following xml structure with multiple levels of hierarchy,

```
<GetData xmlns="http://www.hr-xml.org/3" releaseID="3.3">
<Application>
    <Sender>
        <ID>Person</ID>
    </Sender>
    <Receiver>
        <Component>DataService</Component>
    </Receiver>
</Application>
<CreationDateTime>2015-07-10</CreationDateTime>
<DataArea>
    <HRData>
        <PersonDossier>
            <MasterPerson>
                <PersonID schemeID="MasterPersonId" schemeAgencyID="Agency">654321</PersonID>
                <PersonLegalID schemeID="LegalID" schemeAgencyID="AgencyID">123456789</PersonLegalID>
                <PersonName>
                    <FormattedName formatCode="GivenName, FamilyName">kjddfaad lsfjjo</FormattedName>
                    <GivenName>kjddfaad<GivenName>
                    <FamilyName>lsfjjo</FamilyName>
                </PersonName>
            </MasterPerson>
        </MasterPersonDossier>
    </HRData>
</DataArea>
</GetData>
```

**Question:**
I would like to mask the value of "PersonLegalID" element but rest of the whole xml has to be preserved(I want just 123456789 to be converted to *****6789).

Can someone please suggest an xslt for this? I will further improve it to meet my requirements.

Comment: Does the value in PersonLegalID have a known, fixed length? -- P.S. Please provide a **well-formed** XML input; many of your elements are not properly closed.

Comment: Yes, it is a 9 character length value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to mask the value of "PersonLegalID" element but rest of
>   the whole xml has to be preserved(I want just 123456789 to be
>   converted to *****6789).

In cases like this, where you want to copy everything as is except for a few details, it's best to start with the *identity transform* template as the rule, then add exceptions to override it.

Assuming the ID in question is always 9 digits long, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns3="http://www.hr-xml.org/3">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns3:PersonLegalID/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('*****', substring(., 6))"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of a namespace prefix to address the `PersonLegalID` node.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to build on your input.