# Looking for a utility to mask xml content in form of key value tags

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a usecase where I want to mask my xml which has field and value like below:

```
<root>
    <entries>
        <entry>
            <key>key1</key>
            <value>value1</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>key2</key>
            <value>value2</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>key3</key>
            <value>value3</value>
        </entry>
    </entries>
</root>
```

I want a utility which can does this by providing some configuration where I can just provide the field names that needs to be masked. Writing a full custom code using xpath and than reading the field names explicitly which needs to be masked and than does the masking is not scalable solution considering the addition of fields in the xml in future.

Let me know if there is some utility which can be used for this.

Comment: Use xsl transformation for that. You would define the rule to convert your xml to masked xml.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348734/masking-xml-element-using-xslt
I got this link. But I think in xsl transformation the template that we defined to recognize the field that needs to be masked is actually the xml tag itself whereas in my case field name is the value of <entry> tag. So, can you tell me how to define the template for this case?

Comment: Yep, this answer is pretty much relevant.

Comment: @AlexeyR. can you help with an example how to define the value that needs to be masked in my case as here field name is not the xml tag name. Actual field name is the value for <key> tag.

Comment: What meaning do you put into term "masking"? Can you give an example of what you have (seems that it is already given) and what you expect to get?

Comment: @AlexeyR. I expect the output as :
<root>
    <entries>
        <entry>
            <key>key1</key>
            <value>value1</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>key2</key>
            <value>xxxxx</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>key3</key>
            <value>value3</value>
        </entry>
    </entries>
</root>

Here if you see I want key2 value to be masked with xxxxx. Similarly there can be many such keys out of which i want to mask the values of some of the keys.

Comment: Hi, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should [learn xsl](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_intro.asp). This is a very powerful mechanism allowing you to process your structured xml data.

I am not an expert in xls but I've prepared you an example of solving your issue with xsl. In my example you can choose which keys to mask and which not. Without filtering it would be even easier:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <entries>
                <xsl:for-each select="//value">
                    <xsl:variable name="key" select="./parent::node()/key"/>
                    <entry>
                        <key>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$key"/>
                        </key>
                        <value>
                            <xsl:choose>
                                <xsl:when test="$key='key1'">###</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:when test="$key='key3'">###</xsl:when>
                                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                        </value>
                    </entry>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </entries>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So the output of such transformation will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <entries>
        <entry>
            <key>key1</key>
            <value>###</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>key2</key>
            <value>value2</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>key3</key>
            <value>###</value>
        </entry>
    </entries>
</root>
```

To run this you need to have xsl processor: [How do I run an XSLT file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590085/how-do-i-run-an-xslt-file)

I have tested my solution in [online xsl test tool.](http://xslttest.appspot.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the response @Alexey. I am in process of learning it. Let me try it. I will test and let you know. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: So what was the result of your test?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. Ya it is working now. Thank you. I have another question related to this. Suppose I have the multiple xml object where only the path till <entry> object is different, i.e one is like the above one and other has like <root1><subObject1><subObject2><entries> and than the entry tag. Can, I write a single common xsl file for all of them because i only want to define the key name, irrespective of the root path. So, is it possible? if yes, can you provide a sample for that as well? @Alexey

Comment: It is not possible. See the answer marked as correct in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952562/using-xsl-to-replace-xml-nodes-with-new-nodes

Comment: I checked this post, but this is different case. In this they talk about changing the value of same tag whereas in my case keys are still different only the path to the node is changed.

Comment: The case is different but the answer (first couple sentences) is relevant.

Comment: Can you send me a link or example where I can replace the value of key with # or * equivalent to its length. Here, Iam able to set static 3 characters # for each listed key whereas i want numbers of # to be come as per the length of the key value.

Comment: You should probably raise another question. This is a bad practice to incrementally solve all your problems within one so question. You have stated the original question. It's been answered. Now you have another question.

Comment: Sure will raise another. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Added new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660454/xsl-template-to-replace-each-character-of-string-with-a-custom-character