# xsl template to replace each character of string with a custom character

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have a usecase where I want to transform the xml key value with a custom character equivalent to the length of the value. Xml request that I want to transform is :

```
<root>
    <entries>
        <entry>
            <key>key1</key>
            <value>value1</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>key2</key>
            <value>value2</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>key3</key>
            <value>value3</value>
        </entry>
    </entries>
</root>
```

Current xml template I am using to covert the specific key values to custom values is as suggested in *[Looking for a utility to mask xml content in form of key value tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48279476/looking-for-a-utility-to-mask-xml-content-in-form-of-key-value-tags)*

Now I dont want static 3 # character as my replacement value. I want no. of hash to be equivalent to the value of the key.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit about what you want ? I did not get what you mean by number of hash ?

Comment: Currently <value> tag after transformation is comings as ### whereas i want the value to have the # equivalent to the actual length of the value. So, if key1 has original value as of length 5 than after transformation it should come as #####.  @Sojimanatsu

Comment: What version of XSLT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using XSLT 2.0 or above, you can use `replace()`...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="keys" select="'key1','key2','key3'"/>
  <xsl:param name="char" select="'#'"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="entry[key=$keys]/value/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'.',$char)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you're using XSLT 1.0, you could use `translate()` with a long third argument. This is kinda hacky though and would only handle values as long as the third argument...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="keys" select="'|key1|key2|key3|'"/>
  <xsl:param name="mask" 
    select="'###################################################################'"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value/text()">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($keys,concat('|',../../key,'|'))">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,.,$mask)"/>        
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A better XSLT 1.0 option is to use a recursive template call...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:param name="keys" select="'|key1|key2|key3|'"/>
  <xsl:param name="char" select="'#'"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="value/text()" name="mask">
    <xsl:param name="input" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="toMask" select="substring($input,2)"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($keys,concat('|',../../key,'|'))">
        <xsl:value-of select="$char"/>
        <xsl:if test="string($toMask)">
          <xsl:call-template name="mask">
            <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$toMask"/>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All three of these stylesheets, using this input:

```
<root>
    <entries>
        <entry>
            <key>key1</key>
            <value>value1</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>key2</key>
            <value>value222222</value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>key3</key>
            <value></value>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <key>key4</key>
            <value>leave me alone</value>
        </entry>        
    </entries>
</root>
```

will output:

```
<root>
   <entries>
      <entry>
         <key>key1</key>
         <value>######</value>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <key>key2</key>
         <value>###########</value>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <key>key3</key>
         <value/>
      </entry>
      <entry>
         <key>key4</key>
         <value>leave me alone</value>
      </entry>
   </entries>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Daniel. In real my key name is like ACCT.NUM , ACCT.ID. So when Iam defining them under xsl:param it is throwing error saying syntax error. So, my key name cant have dot in it? @daniel-haley

Comment: @AnkitJain - The xsl:param is just a string, so the dot would be fine. The xsl:param value can be set at runtime; is that what you’re doing or are you hard coding the value in the style sheet like I’m doing in my example?

Comment: Iam harcoding the keys since only some keys needs to be masked. Iam defining like this:
<xsl:param name="keys" select="'ACCT.NUM','ACCT.ID','ACCT.DATE'"/>
This way is saying syntax error. @DanielHaley

Comment: This issue is happening only for solution given for xslt 2.0

Comment: @AnkitJain - That xsl:param is ok for XSLT 2.0, but you need to be sure that you're using an XSLT 2.0 processor ([see list of processors here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info)). Which processor are you using?

Comment: @AnkitJain - Here's a working example using Saxon 9.8 HE: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhp

Comment: Iam using the default xslt2.0 processor that comes with java 8. As Iam working with eclipse which uses JDK1.8, it is using its default xslt processor

Comment: @AnkitJain - Java doesn't have a default XSLT 2.0 processor. The default processor only supports 1.0. (You can verify the version supported by using `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/>` to output the version.) You'll either have to use another processor (like Saxon) or use one of the XSLT 1.0 options I listed in my answer.

Comment: Thanks @daniel for the information. The 1.0 solution is working fine.